# symfony2 command too much data memory limit

Tags: php, memory, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created a command to create events for my application. The command creates more then 700 events, everything is doing fine.

But every event should have more then 250 guests. It means, I must insert more then 175000 guests in one php process.

I've read a lot of things about batch processing and performance optimization for making this work.

But the guestcreation needs too much memory and the creation tooks to much time.
No change that I tested improved the performance.

Does anybody have an idea what I can to to create my data?

Here is the code:

```
// create Events
.
.
.
$events = array(); //List of Events load from the database
$amountG = 250;
$countGuests = 0;
foreach($events as $event){

    for($i=0;$i<$amountG;$i++){                

        $guest = null;
        $guest = $this->createGuest($event); //creates a guest object with random testdata                
        $countGuests++;
        $guest->setPublickey(PublickeyUtils::generatePublickey($countGuests));
        $em->persist($guest);
        if($countGuests%5000 == 0){            
            $em->flush();            
            $em->clear();            
            gc_collect_cycles();
        }

        $glEntry = null;
        unset($glEntry);
    }               
    $event = null;
    unset($event);
}

$em->flush();            
$em->clear();
```

Every flush needs 3% memory, so it means, all the 175.000 Entries will never be flushed because the memory limit is reached.

And every 5000 Entries needs more then 10seconds.
increading the amount of flushs will me more slowly.

What I've also done is to call the script with the options `--env=prod and -no-debug` to prevent logging.

What is the best way to make it work more performantly?

Comment: I don't get why your loading in the Events entities - they are not used within the loop - i would suggest they are taking a lot of the memory - Have a look at [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html#mass-object-processing) for processing objects  - loading and detaching of objects when they have been used

Comment: sorry, i forgot that the guest has a relation to the event. so i need the entity.

Comment: you could span a php process for each loop , or use Messaging ( MQ ;.. )

Comment: can you explain it with more details please @mpm ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you currently have it set to, you could also consider increasing php's [memory limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Comment: there is no memeory limit set.

Comment: There always is, if you haven't set it explicitly, it will be set based on the defaults as per the manual page: 128M currently,  8M before PHP 5.2.0, and 16M in PHP 5.2.0. What does `phpinfo();` tell you ?

Comment: ini_get('memory_limit') is -1. it means there is no memory limit.

Comment: So you did set a memory limit, you just set it to infinite.  From my perspective that is different than "there is no memory limit set"

Answer (score 0):

The solution ist to make inserts without any objects:

```
$em->getConnection()->insert('entity', $array);
```